# How to build a kafka producer in Python that reads two CSV files and publishes to 2 Kafka topics?

Tags: python, csv, apache-kafka

I have two datasets - A.csv and B.csv - and I want to implement a Pyspark streaming application that can find the most popular names (name column in the csv) across these two datasets.

The application should have a producer that reads the CSV files and publishes rides to corresponding Kafka topics paralelly, such as A and B.

Next, I want to use Pyspark streaming to read data from these two Kafka topics and I want to apply aggregations to find the most popular names across these two datasets.

Can anyone provide me with guidance on how to implement this Pyspark streaming application and what code would be required to achieve the above? Thanks.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import csv
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Connect to Kafka broker
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=["localhost:9092"])

# Function to publish data to Kafka topic
def publish_to_topic(topic, data):
    producer.send(topic, value=bytes(str(data), "utf-8"))


# Read and publish CSV files in parallel
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    # A CSV file
    with open(“A.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            a_data = {
                “Name”: row[“name”]
            }
            # Publish to Kafka topic
            executor.submit(publish_to_topic, “topic_a”, a_data)

    # B CSV file
    with open(“B.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            b_data = {
                “Name”: row[“name_”],
            }
            # Publish to Kafka topic
            executor.submit(publish_to_topic, “topic_b”, b_data)
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck doing this? And why do you need Kafka to read two static files only once?

Comment: The Spark documentation has exactly the guidance you need for both reading csv and writing to kafka, but you really don't Spark since you could use any other Kafka Python client

Comment: I have added some code above where I'm attempting to read 2 CSV files and publish their contents to Kafka topics simultaneously. However, I'm facing an issue where the publishing process does not seem to be working simultaneously as intended.

Comment: You asked how to do this in Spark, so did you mean to show us what you've tried in Spark? Why do you need to open both csv in the same script? One script should be able to open any CSV file, so pass it as a parameter to the script, then run two processes, for that scrip, for each file, in parallel

Answer (score 0):

`with open` and the following for loop are blocking calls

You'd need something like this to actually open both files in parallel

```
def publish_to_topic(topic, filename):
    global producer
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            value = line.encode()
            producer.send(topic, value=value)
    producer.flush()

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    for name in ['a', 'b']:
        executor.submit(publish_to_topic, f'topic_{name}', f'{name}.csv')
```